# How to refresh id_token from Google OIDC service?

Tags: google-oauth, openid-connect, google-openid

I am building an SPA application (react.js based) that needs id_token issued from Google, and I need to refresh it when the initial id_token is expired because the id_token is used / checked in the backend of my application.

I am reading Google OIDC's instruction, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect, but I did not find a recommended way to get new Google id_token without forcing users to go through sign-in page (which is for sure an unpleasant experience for the users)

How should I achieve the above id_token refreshing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the used flow, but I believe you are using `Authorization Code flow with PKCE`, so you should to have also refresh token, which can be used for token refresh. Doc: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#refresh-tokens